# Problems returning a value from navigator.geolocation function attached to a form event

Tags: jquery, geolocation

I have an event handler attached to a form switch

```
$("#formSwitch").on('change', function() {

var geoOptions = {
    maximumAge: 5 * 60 * 1000,
    }

var geoSuccess = function(position) {

      /***** do some stuff here ****/
      return ( true );

      };

var geoError = function(error) {

   /***** do some stuff here ****/
   return ( false );

   };

var status = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, geoOptions);

console.log(status); /******** Geolocation works but gives undefined here ******/

return(status);                         

});
```

And I want to both trigger the switch and determine geoLocation status so I have tried:

```
 if( !$("#formSwitch").val("on").change() ) {

    /****** geoLocation is false so do some stuff here ******/

    }
```

This triggers the switch, calls the geoLocation function fine but does not receive a return value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider checking whether or not the browser supports geolocation:`if (navigator.geolocation !== undefined){/* do geolocation stuff here */}`

Some browsers have started blocking geolocation under certain conditions in loca development, and maybe it is failing silently in your browser: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only#does_this_affect_local_development

Additionally, since the geolocation callbacks are asynchronous, it might be better practice to place console logs inside of geoSuccess and geoError callbacks. It's possible that the console.log is being evaluated before the getCurrentPosition has returned anything.

Try adding the code dependent on the success/fail callbacks into the callbacks themselves:

```js
var geoOptions = {
    maximumAge: 5 * 60 * 1000,
    }

var geoSuccess = function(position) {

      /***** do some stuff here ****/
      console.log(true);

      };

var geoError = function(error) {

   /***** do some stuff here ****/
   console.log(false);

   };

var status = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, geoOptions);
```

Comment: No navigator.geolocation returns true.

Comment: And geoSuccess and geoError are passed as callback functions to ensure they run after the request has completed.

Comment: True, but your code continues executing after you call getCurrentPosition. It doesn't wait for the callbacks to resolve before moving onto the next line of code, so status is undefined until one of the callbacks resolves. That is why the console.log is undefined.